# Running Multiple Function calls inside pyspark in parallel

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have a function which i am running in pyspark-shell

```
import pandas as pd
def compute(x):
    data = pd.read_csv("/tmp/data_{}.csv".format(x))
    # Some Spark processing
    # Writes back final output in tmp
```

I want to run this in parallel over a list of x.
I tried this -

```
x_list=[14,63]
from multiprocessing import Process
for x in x_list:
    p = Process(target = compute, args = (x,))
    p.start()
```

This finishes the script. I want them to run fully before script finishes.

How can i achieve this ?

Comment: You're missing a comma: it should be `(x, )` instead of `(x)`. The former is a tuple with one element; the latter is an integer because the parentheses do nothing.

Comment: Yes, it helped putting a "," but now the process start and my script finishes. How can I let both of them run completely before my script finishes ?

Comment: Edited the question too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to keep a handle on each of the processes you started and [`join()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.join) on them:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import pandas as pd

def compute(x):
    data = pd.read_csv("/tmp/data_{}.csv".format(x))
    # Some Spark processing
    # Writes back final output in tmp

x_list = [14,63]
processes = []
for x in x_list:
    p = Process(target=compute, args=(x,))
    processes.append(p)
    p.start()
for p in processes:
    p.join()
```